# Instagram Messenger API Registering Webhooks

Tags: instagram-graph-api, facebook-webhooks, facebook-messages

I'm building an integration that manages Instagram Messenger chats on behalf of clients. In the past I've done an integration for Facebook Messenger.

I'm stuck on how to actually get the client Instagram subscribed to our Instagram Messaging webhook events.

The 'Setup webhooks' section on the [Instagram Messaging docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/instagram) just points to the [general webhook setup for the messenger platform](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhooks), which explains to use the /PAGE-ID/subscribed_apps endpoint specifying the fields (events) to subscribe to. I do this with the previous Facebook Messenger integration, but with Instagram I'm running into several problems.

First I tried to subscribe to the following fields **messages, message_reactions, messaging_seen**

An error response explains it's not possible to subscribe to messaging_seen.

Then I try with only  **messages, message_reactions** and get the error pages_messaging permission is required which is not mentioned in the Instagram Messaging docs.

I'm only aware of these issues because I'm failing the App Review because the webhooks are not working for the reviewers. In testing my own Facebook Page / Instagram Business account it is working fine presumably because I own the Page/IG account I'm trying to connect. Because of that I've been able to record a complete video of the functionality, but the reviewer feedback keeps implying that they also need recreate that functionality themselves to pass it.

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58545332/why-is-the-instagram-graph-api-webhook-not-working/58621982#58621982) suggests to use mocking, but I think that's for the creating the video rather than for the reviewers to use. I'm also not sure how you would mock something like the delete function without the webhooks anyway.

I haven't been able to find much information about this, so any pointers would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you find the solution? stuck with this too

Comment: In the end we removed the step to register the webhook events via the /subscribed_apps endpoint. We configured the events in the developer dashboard under Messenger > Instagram Settings (then Edit Subscriptions in the Webhook panel). From what I can tell the /subscribed_apps endpoint is not for Instagram webhooks. Something not made clear in the documentation.

Comment: To get past the App Review we had to add the pages_messaging permission to the scope, this worked for us as we already that permission approved for our previous Facebook integration. We removed it after approval was granted. Unfortunately, I don't have a suggestion if you don't have that permission. Overall a painful process.

Comment: @Alan 6 months later and stuck with this too! How did you configure the events in the developer dashboard for your client? I seem to only be able to add pages that I own.

Comment: @jc023 I think that's all you need to do. Use the Edit Subscriptions button in the Messenger > Instagram Settings and those events selected there will be registered when the user authenticates to your app. You can't use the /subscribed_apps endpoint to register events for Instagram, it's for Facebook Messenger only