# How to test Instagram Webhooks and get approved?

Tags: instagram-graph-api, facebook-webhooks

Background:

The webhook allows to receive the context and information about the interaction of Instagrammers with particular users, the official documentation states that [`instagram_manage_messages` permission should have *Advanced Acess Level* to receive the webhook notifications](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/webhooks#endpoint-requirements:%7E:text=If%20the%20app%20permissions%20don%27t%20have%20an%20access%20level%20of%20Advanced%20Access%2C%20the%20app%20doesn%27t%20receive%20webhook%20notifications.)

Problem:

Unless the review is not complete of a particular App(meta), can't obtain the Advanced Access Level for `instagram_manage_messages`, whereas the App review requires the demonstration of the implementation of features with the app.

However, the developer portal allows the dev to test the webhook, which we tested by clicking each type of notification from the portal. But the demonstration of the features is required (video clip)

How to test the features or at least collect evidence of a fairly working demo to get approval?

I went through this [Why is the Instagram Graph API webhook not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58621982) where the dev says the policy prohibits one from testing webhooks(Instagram), I agree, but nothing close to recording a specimen for approval.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make the webhook for instagram work.

1. Create one more real facebook account for testing.
2. Then create new instagram account using the new facebook account. I created it in instagram mobile app. It must be bind to the facebook account.
3. Sign up in developers.facebook.com with this new facebook account.
4. In developers.facebook.com, in your application, add this new facebook user as a tester.
5. Finally, with new instagram account try to send messages to you instagram account which bind to webhook. Your webhook must start recieving webhook events.

Now, you can test your app and write screencast.

Comment: Did you get the permission approved by using above steps? In my case, the Facebook verification team is not able to log-in with the new IG account (linked to the FB account and which is able to call the webhook) due to Suspicious Login Attempt. When they try with their own IG account, the webhook is not getting called.

Comment: @DipenBhikadya no, I am still trying to get the permission. I have sent more than 10 requests to get this permission. But they always reject with different reasons. They manage to log in with my test account, they send few messages to my bot every time when they review.

Comment: I believe we have moved a step closer. Enabling 2FA for the end-user IG account and sharing backup codes with them have allowed them to try out sending the messages. They are expecting support for story mentions and story replies too before the permission can be approved.

Comment: @DipenBhikadya How did you demonstrate the story mentioned in the screencast for the review? Looks like story mention cannot be performed from Desktop browser. I have implemeneted handling story mention but am struggle to show it in the screencast.